# choosing standard deviation parameter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, probability

If I want to use the gaussian random number generator in MATLAB

```
R = normrnd(mu,sigma)
```

Let `mu = 1`.

The question is how to choose sigma? If I want 90% of the values to be near 1.Let us say +/-0.7

Thanks

Comment: It depends what you mean by "near".  You should probably refer to the graph at e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "near 1".  In a normal distribution, 90% of the values will be within 1.65 standard deviations of the mean (about 5 % above and about 5% below).  For example, if you want 90% of the values to be between 0.5 and 1.5, you need

```
1.65 * sigma ~= 0.5
sigma ~= 0.5 / 1.65
sigma ~= 0.3
```

You can look at a normal distribution [table](http://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3671.htm) to look up the other values.
The table (excerpted below) states that ~45% of the values of a normal distribution fall between the mean and 1.65*sigma above the mean.  Since the distribution is symmetric, ~45%  of the values fall between the mean and 1.65*sigma below the mean and ~90% fall within +- 1.65 * sigma of the mean.

```
                           Area under the Normal Curve from 0 to X

X       0.00    0.01    0.02    0.03    0.04    0.05    0.06    0.07    0.08    0.09
1.5     0.43319 0.43448 0.43574 0.43699 0.43822 0.43943 0.44062 0.44179 0.44295 0.44408
1.6     0.44520 0.44630 0.44738 0.44845 0.44950 0.45053 0.45154 0.45254 0.45352 0.45449
1.7     0.45543 0.45637 0.45728 0.45818 0.45907 0.45994 0.46080 0.46164 0.46246 0.46327
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I have tried google to understand practical aspect of standard deviation before asking but things are still not clear. what will be the effect of sigma?

Comment: you mean if I want 90% to be between 1 and -1, to find sigma I do 1/1.65? Another question: what is the maximum value generated (farthest from mean)

Comment: The is no upper bound on the maximum value generated for a normal distribution.  All you can say is there is a small probability of a sample from the distribution being greater than a certain value.

Comment: So David,I can't generate a random gaussian numbers from -4 to 4 with mean 1 and sd=0.7/1.65?

Comment: so the probability of getting 3*(0.7/1.65) is 0.1% so it is very rare (not impossible)to get value greater than 1.27 am I right?

Comment: You should expect the samples to be greater than 3*sigma, approximately 0.14% of the time.  That would be considered rare in many contexts, but you shouldn't assume it won't happen in your code.